# Transferlearning with tensorflow hub inception v1 doesn't predict well

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to make a transfer learning with inceptionv1 but the classifier is not working well predicting one image, what is wrong?

```
    from skimage.transform import resize
    m = tf.keras.Sequential([hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v1/classification/4")])     # load the tensorflow hub model
    m.build([None, 224, 224, 3])
    rimg = resize(img, output_shape=(1,224,224,3),anti_aliasing=True)   # resize and reshape the image to [1,224,224,3] 
    rimg = (rimg-np.min(rimg))/(np.max(rimg)-np.min(rimg)).astype(np.float32)  # normalize the image to a [0,1] range
    logits = m(rimg) # feed the image into the model to obtain the logits 
    probs  = np.exp(logits)/(np.sum(np.exp(logits))) # convert logits to probabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying min-max normalization while dividing each pixel value by 255 should be used instead. Specifically, the least intense pixel value possible (0) should be mapped to 0 while the maximum (255) should be mapped to 1. Thus, an image like `[64, 128]` should be mapped to `[0.25, 0.5]` while your normalization maps it to `[0, 1]` instead.